# Flask / Docker: Error: Could not import 'project.main.python'

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I am trying to build and run a flask application using docker on GCP.

My file structure is as follows:

```
> /project
>     static (contains some images)
>     templates (contains html files)
>     tmp_data (contains some data that is created during usage of the app)
>     __init__.py
>     auth.py (app has a login feature, this script helps authorize them)
>     main.py
>     Dockerfile
>     some other function scripts
```

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN pip3 install Flask gunicorn scipy seaborn matplotlib pandas numpy flask_excel flask_login flask_sqlalchemy

COPY . /project

WORKDIR project

ENV FLASK_APP=main.python

# run flask in dev mode
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

EXPOSE 5001:5000

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

My main.py file is as follows:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from . import db
import flask_excel as excel
import json

# user written imports (not sure why it wants relative imports now?)
from .generate_data import get_truncated_normal, create_data
from .create_graphs import plot_graph, hist_plot, bar_plot, pie_plot, data_comments
from .generate_html_file import generate_html

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

... some functions and flask views ...
```

When I build my app (successfully) using the command

```
~/some_upper_folder/project (my_sandbox)$ docker build -t project .
```

and then run it with the command

```
~/some_upper_folder/project (my_sandbox)$ docker run project
```

I get the error:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'main.python' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
 Try 'flask run --help' for help.

 Error: Could not import 'project.main.python'.
```

I am not sure why this is occurring, I'm guessing this is due to the fact that I'm referencing an incorrect directory?

NOTE: The app is working correctly, I can run it using a venv created in another folder not seen here

Comment: Try to change ENV FLASK_APP=main.python to ENV FLASK_APP=main and rerun. What do you get ?

Comment: change the env variable to main and followed the exact steps above. I then get the error message `Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'project.main'. Use 'FLASK_APP=project.main:name' to specify one.` when running the command `docker run project`

Comment: I am assuming that the run command would be something like main.run(...) in your code. If that is the case, try using this: FLASK_APP=project.main:main'

Comment: With those changes i get `Error: Could not import 'project.project.main'.`. When I have locally deployed this app I usually just follow these steps: (create env) `python3 -m venv auth`. (activate) `source auth/bin/activate` and then finally set some env variables `export FLASK_APP=project
export FLASK_DEBUG=1`. Before finally just `flask run`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem since I have the same structure for the project as yours.
After changing the FLASK_APP to the folder name resolved the problem for me. For your case, it should be like this:

```
ENV FLASK_APP=/project
```